# In what order are methods called when you have class hierarchy?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
class Mobile {
  double memory_util;
  public:
  virtual void power_save(double duration) = 0;
};

class Laptop : public Mobile {
  bool is_unlocked;
  protected:
  bool is_charged;
  public:
  void power_save(double duration);
  virtual double remaining_time();
};

class NegativeNumber {}; 
class IPad : public Laptop {
  int generation;
  public:
  void power_save(double duration);
  bool isJailBroken();
};

class HPLaptop : public Laptop {
  int warranty_years; 
  public:
  void extend_warranty(int years);
};

class HPdv6 : public HPLaptop {
  bool repaired;
  public:
  double remaining_time(){  return HPLaptop::remaining_time();  }
  bool is_repaired { return repaired; }
};
```

And you wanted to do the following:

```
int main () {
  Mobile* d = new HPdv6();
  Laptop *s = d;
  d->power_save(100);
  cout << “remaining operation time: ” <<
  s->remaining_time() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Which methods would actually be called here?  I understand that Mobile is a virtual function, but I'm unsure how to deal with the class hierarchy when you have pointers like this.  Are there any tips about class hierarchy that will make problems that deal with various inherited classes easier to understand?

Thank you.

Comment: `Laptop *s = d;` shouldn't compile, as you need some sort of downcast.

Comment: Also, assuming that it does compile...

Comment: You need to cast it via `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` because it needs an explicit cast to go down the inheritance chain. Here's the error I'm talking about: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d3a1106b6b8f6728c9fb75a5adb81b63

Answer (score 3):

Once you sorted out the error in `Laptop *s = d;` (see [`static_cast<>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)), you would find that `HPdv6`'s `remaining_time()` would be called and `Laptop`'s `power_save()` would be called.

To over-simplify, the functions are resolved by starting at `HPdv6` and walking up the inheritance tree until the method is found. `IPad` won't be used because it doesn't appear between `HPdv6` and `Laptop`, it sits in a separate branch.

If you want the non-oversimplified version, look up `vtables`.  Here is the Wikipedia article on them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: If it goes up the inheritance tree, why doesn't d->power_save(100) call Ipad's power_save?  And s->remaining_time() should call Hpdv6's remaining_time(), right?

Comment: Why is laptop's power_save() called and not Ipad's power_save()?

Comment: Sorry, I edited that first sentence for grammar.  If you picture your classes as a tree, `IPad` is in the tree, but it isn't in the chain between `Laptop` and `HPdv6`.